# PHP RegEx Replacement With Values From the Original

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to replace a series of plane codes that are strings in PHP.

For example, **757-252 string should become a 752 string**

It takes the first two digits before the hypen, and the first digit after the hyphen.

There are three conditions that make this complicated where I can't just use explode and I think need to use RegEx:

1. The digit before the hyphen may be more than just a single digit, and it MAY be alpha numeric.
2. The last three digits in the example above is a variable length and can be alpha or numeric.
3. There are values that DON'T fit this pattern that I need to be left alone (i.e. DHC-8-103)

Any thoughts

**RegEx - Working at RegExPal.com**

```
7[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]+\-[0-9a-z-A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

**PHP Attempt to Replace Not Working**

```
$aircraft = '757-252';

$pattern = '/(7)(0-9)(0-9a-zA-Z)+-(0-9a-zA-Z)(0-9a-zA-Z)+/';
$replacement = '\\1\\2\\4';

$aircraft_code = preg_replace($pattern , $replacement , $aircraft);
```

Comment: For starters, you've lost the `[ ]` brackets from your groups, so they aren't functioning as ranges in character classes like you expect. Instead, you get the literal string "0-9", for example.

Comment: I originally had them as ` [ ] ` and that didn't work either.  I saw in other PHP specific examples where there weren't the ` [ ] ` but rather the ` ( ) ` so I thought I'd try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for the beginning of `$aircraft` value with `^` then capture first 2 digits and the one after hyphen:

```
^(7\d).+?(\d).*$
```

And your code:

```
$aircraft = '757-252';
$pattern = '/^(7\d).+?(\d).*$/';
$replacement = '$1$2';
$aircraft_code = preg_replace($pattern , $replacement , $aircraft);
// echo $aircraft_code; // output: 752
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has changed from the working Regex (missing capture groups), I think your pattern needs to be this:

```
$pattern = '/(7)([0-9])([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9a-z-A-Z])([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/';
```

I'm also a bit rusty at PHP, but I don't think you need to escape the backslashes in your replacement string if you're using `'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
$pattern = '/.*\b(7\d)[^-]*-(\w).*/';
$replacement = '$1$2';
```

Comment: @revo: It'll give `75w` as expected.

Comment: `w` is not expected as an alphabetical character

Comment: @revo: This must be clarified by OP. For me, it's OK.

Comment: It's clarified already `first two digits before the hypen, and the first digit after the hyphen.`

Comment: @revo: Right, but the second condition says: `The last three digits in the example above is a variable length and can be alpha or numeric.`

Comment: When seeing those two above statements together, it turns to be `752` out of `757-w25` to me and as your replacements, the result will include other last characters too e.g. `757-252` results to `75252`

Comment: You are both correct, because I was confusing in my instructions.  Truth be told, the solution I am looking for in the real world, I needed both of your solutions.  I liked Revo's the best for Boeing aircraft because their pattern is a bit more "uniform" - however, I needed M42 to handle the Airbus, McDonnel Douglas, Embraer, and others.

You guys were HUGE helps here.  I really appreciate it.  I feel like this gives me a much better foundation with RegEx and for that I am very, very grateful.

Comment: Also, I don't have 15 reputation points yet (I am new), so I can't upvote this, and I had to choose only one answer.  But this answer should be up voted and considered a valid answer as well.